# Get time difference between datetimes

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, difference

How to get the difference between 2 times? Example:

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";

//expected result:
"00:39:30"
```

I tried:

```
var now = moment("04/09/2013 15:00:00");
var then = moment("04/09/2013 14:20:30");

console.log(moment(moment.duration(now.diff(then))).format("hh:mm:ss"))
//outputs 10:39:30
```

What is "10" there? I am at utc-0300. Result of `moment.duration(now.diff(then))` is a duration with correct internal values:

```
 days: 0
 hours: 0
 milliseconds: 0
 minutes: 39
 months: 0
 seconds: 30
 years: 0
```

How to convert a momentjs duration to a time interval? I can use:

```
duration.get("hours") +":"+ duration.get("minutes") +:+ duration.get("seconds")
```

But is there something more elegant? `now` is:

```
Tue Apr 09 2013 15:00:00 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)…}
```

And `moment(moment.duration(now.diff(then)))` is:

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 22:39:30 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)…}
```

The value is -0200 because for 31/12/1969 daylight saving time was used.

Comment: "but I am sure that i do not like dates" :P Did you ever read this: http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/trivia.html ?

Answer (score 421, accepted):

**This approach will work ONLY when the total duration is less than 24 hours:**

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";

moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")

// outputs: "00:39:30"
```

If you have 24 hours or more, the hours will reset to zero with the above approach, so it is not ideal.

**If you want to get a valid response for durations of 24 hours or greater,** then you'll have to do something like this instead:

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

// outputs: "48:39:30"
```

Note that I'm using the utc time as a shortcut.  You could pull out `d.minutes()` and `d.seconds()` separately, but you would also have to zeropad them.

This is necessary because the ability to format a `duration` objection is not currently in moment.js.  [It has been requested here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048).  However, there is a third-party plugin called [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) that is specifically for this purpose:

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = d.format("hh:mm:ss");

// outputs: "48:39:30"
```

Answer (score 76):

Your problem is in passing the result of moment.duration() back into moment() before formatting it; this results in moment() interpreting it as a time relative to the Unix epoch.

It doesn't give you exactly the format you're looking for, but

`moment.duration(now.diff(then)).humanize()`

would give you a useful format like "40 minutes". If you're really keen on that specific formatting, you'll have to build a new string yourself. A cheap way would be

`[diff.asHours(), diff.minutes(), diff.seconds()].join(':')`

where `var diff = moment.duration(now.diff(then))`. This doesn't give you the zero-padding on single digit values. For that, you might want to consider something like [underscore.string](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/) - although it seems like a long way to go just for a few extra zeroes. :)

Comment: you'll have to use `asHours` instead of `hours`, and pull off the decimals. Otherwise it would have the same problem you caught in my answer. :)

Comment: Note, it would be wise to use:    
`[Math.floor(diff.asHours()), diff.minutes(), diff.seconds()].join(':')` in order to get the desired result. without a decimal in the first part

Answer (score 72):

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') //[days, years, months, seconds, ...]
//Result 1
```

**Worked for me**

See more in
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: this only works for dates. OP wanted to have the time difference

Comment: This is the simplest solution which works. Yes, with timestamps too.

Answer (score 36):

If you want difference of two timestamp into total days,hours and minutes only, not in months and years .

```
var now  = "01/08/2016 15:00:00";
var then = "04/02/2016 14:20:30";
var diff = moment.duration(moment(then).diff(moment(now)));
```

diff contains 2 months,23 days,23 hours and 20 minutes. But we need result only in days,hours and minutes so the simple solution is:

```
var days = parseInt(diff.asDays()); //84

var hours = parseInt(diff.asHours()); //2039 hours, but it gives total hours in given miliseconds which is not expacted.

hours = hours - days*24;  // 23 hours

var minutes = parseInt(diff.asMinutes()); //122360 minutes,but it gives total minutes in given miliseconds which is not expacted.

minutes = minutes - (days*24*60 + hours*60); //20 minutes.
```

Final result will be : 84 days, 23 hours, 20 minutes.

Answer (score 20):

When you call `diff`, moment.js calculates the difference in milliseconds.
If the milliseconds is passed to `duration`, it is used to calculate duration which is correct.
However. when you pass the same milliseconds to the `moment()`, it calculates the date that is milliseconds from(after) epoch/unix time that is January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT).
That is why you get 1969 as the year together with wrong hour.

```
duration.get("hours") +":"+ duration.get("minutes") +":"+ duration.get("seconds")
```

So, I think this is how you should do it since moment.js does not offer `format` function for duration. Or you can write a simple wrapper to make it easier/prettier.

Answer (score 17):

This should work fine.

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);

console.log(d.days() + ':' + d.hours() + ':' + d.minutes() + ':' + d.seconds());
```

Answer (score 10):

If we want only hh:mm:ss, we can use a function like that:

```
//param: duration in milliseconds
MillisecondsToTime: function(duration) {
    var seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
        , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24)
        , days  = parseInt(duration/(1000*60*60*24));

    var hoursDays = parseInt(days*24);
    hours += hoursDays;
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: I don't see moment usage anywhere in you answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var aa = duration.asHours();
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
Math.floor(duration.asHours()) + moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format(":mm:ss")
```

It's better to do

```
moment.utc(total.asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work for any date in the format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss**

```
const moment=require("moment");
let startDate=moment("2020-09-16 08:39:27");
const endDate=moment();


const duration=moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate))
console.log(duration.asSeconds());
 console.log(duration.asHours());
```

Answer (score 2):

In ES8 using moment, now and start being moment objects.

```
const duration = moment.duration(now.diff(start));
const timespan = duration.get("hours").toString().padStart(2, '0') +":"+ duration.get("minutes").toString().padStart(2, '0') +":"+ duration.get("seconds").toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Typescript:** following should work,

```
export const getTimeBetweenDates = ({
  until,
  format
}: {
  until: number;
  format: 'seconds' | 'minutes' | 'hours' | 'days';
}): number => {
  const date = new Date();
  const remainingTime = new Date(until * 1000);
  const getFrom = moment([date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate()]);
  const getUntil = moment([remainingTime.getUTCFullYear(), remainingTime.getUTCMonth(), remainingTime.getUTCDate()]);
  const diff = getUntil.diff(getFrom, format);
  return !isNaN(diff) ? diff : null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**DATE TIME BASED INPUT**

```
    var dt1 = new Date("2019-1-8 11:19:16");
    var dt2 = new Date("2019-1-8 11:24:16");


    var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) ;
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
    diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);


    var response = {
        status : 200,
        Hour : hours,
        Mins : mins
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
"status": 200,
"Hour": 0,
"Mins": 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is valid for all cases (difference between dates less than 24 hours and difference greater than 24 hours):

```js
// Defining start and end variables
let start = moment('04/09/2013 15:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
let end   = moment('04/09/2013 14:20:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');

// Getting the difference: hours (h), minutes (m) and seconds (s)
let h  = end.diff(start, 'hours');
let m  = end.diff(start, 'minutes') - (60 * h);
let s  = end.diff(start, 'seconds') - (60 * 60 * h) - (60 * m);

// Formating in hh:mm:ss (appends a left zero when num < 10)
let hh = ('0' + h).slice(-2);
let mm = ('0' + m).slice(-2);
let ss = ('0' + s).slice(-2);

console.log(`${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`); // 00:39:30
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return biggest time period diff like (4 seconds, 2 minutes, 1 hours, 2 days, 3 weeks, 4 months, 5 years).
I use this for notification recent time.

```
function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    let arrDate = ["seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks", "months", "years"];
    let dateMap = arrDate.map(e => moment(endDate).diff(startDate, e));
    let index = 6 - dateMap.filter(e => e == 0).length;
    return {
        type: arrDate[index] ?? "seconds",
        value: dateMap[index] ?? 0
    };
}
```

Example:

```
dateDiff("2021-06-09 01:00:00", "2021-06-09 04:01:01")

{type: "hours", value: 3}
```

```
dateDiff("2021-06-09 01:00:00", "2021-06-12 04:01:01")

{type: "days", value: 3}
```

```
dateDiff("2021-06-09 01:00:00", "2021-06-09 01:00:10")

{type: "seconds", value: 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple function with typescript

```
const diffDuration: moment.Duration = moment.duration(moment('2017-09-04 12:55').diff(moment('2017-09-02 13:26')));
setDiffTimeString(diffDuration);

function setDiffTimeString(diffDuration: moment.Duration) {
  const str = [];
  diffDuration.years() > 0 ? str.push(`${diffDuration.years()} year(s)`) : null;
  diffDuration.months() > 0 ? str.push(`${diffDuration.months()} month(s)`) : null;
  diffDuration.days() > 0 ? str.push(`${diffDuration.days()} day(s)`) : null;
  diffDuration.hours() > 0 ? str.push(`${diffDuration.hours()} hour(s)`) : null;
  diffDuration.minutes() > 0 ? str.push(`${diffDuration.minutes()} minute(s)`) : null;
  console.log(str.join(', '));
} 
// output: 1 day(s), 23 hour(s), 29 minute(s)
```

for generate javascript https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Answer (score 0):

InTime=06:38,Outtime=15:40

```
 calTimeDifference(){
        this.start = dailyattendance.InTime.split(":");
        this.end = dailyattendance.OutTime.split(":");
        var time1 = ((parseInt(this.start[0]) * 60) + parseInt(this.start[1]))
        var time2 = ((parseInt(this.end[0]) * 60) + parseInt(this.end[1]));
        var time3 = ((time2 - time1) / 60);
        var timeHr = parseInt(""+time3);
        var  timeMin = ((time2 - time1) % 60);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EPOCH TIME DIFFERENCE USING MOMENTJS**:

To Get Difference between two epoch times:

**Syntax:**
`moment.duration(moment(moment(date1).diff(moment(date2)))).asHours()`

**Difference in Hours:**
`moment.duration(moment(moment(1590597744551).diff(moment(1590597909877)))).asHours()`

**Difference in minutes:**
`moment.duration(moment(moment(1590597744551).diff(moment(1590597909877)))).asMinutes().toFixed()`

**Note:** You could remove `.toFixed()` if you need precise values.

**Code:**

```
const moment = require('moment')

console.log('Date 1',moment(1590597909877).toISOString())
console.log('Date 2',moment(1590597744551).toISOString())
console.log('Date1 - Date 2 time diffrence is : ',moment.duration(moment(moment(1590597909877).diff(moment(1590597744551)))).asMinutes().toFixed()+' minutes')
```

**Refer working example here:**
https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinDearDimension

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between two-moment format dates or javascript Date format indifference of minutes the most optimum solution is

```
const timeDiff = moment.duration((moment(apptDetails.end_date_time).diff(moment(apptDetails.date_time)))).asMinutes()
```

you can change the difference format as you need by just replacing the asMinutes() function

Answer (score 0):

If you want a localized number of days between two dates (`startDate`, `endDate`):

```
var currentLocaleData = moment.localeData("en");
var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var nbDays = Math.floor(duration.asDays()); // complete days
var nbDaysStr = currentLocaleData.relativeTime(returnVal.days, false, "dd", false);
```

`nbDaysStr` will contain something like '3 days';

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/ for information on how to display the amount of hours or month, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple with **moment**
below code will return diffrence in hour from current time:

```
moment().diff('2021-02-17T14:03:55.811000Z', "h")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getRemainingTime = (t2) => {
  const t1 = new Date().getTime();
  let ts = (t1-t2.getTime()) / 1000;

  var d = Math.floor(ts / (3600*24));
  var h = Math.floor(ts % (3600*24) / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(ts % 3600 / 60);
  var s = Math.floor(ts % 60);

  console.log(d, h, m, s)

}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.