# How to Calculate Total Time in HH:MM Format in Jquery For Data & Time in seperate text-boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Suppose I have 5 text-boxes respectively For Start Date, Start Time, End Date, End time  & another Text box For Showing the Result all inside a Grid View in asp.net. I want to Calculate the difference between the two dates along with the time also for key up event of the End time text box & show it into the text box which is used for Showing Result.

My Input will be like this:

For Date 20/08/2014
For Time : 17:55

I am new to j query & unable to search the exact  or similar solution for my problem. Can any one help here?
Thanks in advance.

```
var start = $('#start_date').val();
var end = $('#end_date').val();

// end - start returns difference in milliseconds 
var diff = new Date(end - start);

// get days
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

Example

var start = new Date("2010-04-01"),
    end   = new Date(),
    diff  = new Date(end - start),
    days  = diff/1000/60/60/24;

days; //=> 8.525845775462964
```

Got Above Solution from stack overflow itself but this is not like exactly mine. i have date & time both in separate text boxes.

Comment: Hello, do you have an example of what you've already tried? Can you provide a jsfiddle example? 
Thanks!

Comment: Still i am finding for solution . i don't have much idea about jquery.

Comment: But i have found few example to work with only 2 textboxes & only for date but not for date & time in separate textboxes.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Please Check My Edited Portion.

Comment: Your problem isn't with the jQuery part of it, it's with the Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moment.js is a great idea

```
$( "#endtime" ).keyup(function() {
var startdt = new Date($("#startdate").val() + " " + $("#starttime").val());

var enddt = new Date($("#enddate").val() + " " + $("#endtime").val());

var diff = enddt - startdt;

var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
diff -=  days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);

var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
diff -= seconds * (1000);

$("#result").val(days + " days : " + hours + " hours : " + mins + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds");
```

})

here you can find this working sample [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vk1ph6df/6/)

I wrote it "on fly" , so it could be not really elegant but works.

Be sure to check the validity of your input values

Comment: Thanks ! Now i got the idea From Your Example.

Comment: Now i will try to implement this on my gridview Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment.js library. It can easily do a lot of operations with date and time.

Look at this SO Q&A:

[Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)