# How to get difference between 2 Dates in Years, Months and days using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get difference between 2 Dates in Years, Months and days using moment.js?
For example the difference between **4/5/2014** & **2/22/2013** should be calculated as **1 Year, 1 Month and 14 Days**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the time difference between two datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: Actually, not a duplicate.  The dup covers hours,minutes,seconds difference.  It's a different problem when you're talking about calendar months.

Comment: @Nawaf - Are the years correct in your question? They are both 2013.

Comment: You are correct Matt. I did fix the dates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moment.js can't handle this scenario directly.  It does allow you to take the difference between two moments, but the result is an elapsed duration of time in milliseconds.  Moment does have a [Duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object, but it defines a month as a fixed unit of 30 days - which we know is not always the case.

Fortunately, there is a plugin already created for moment called ["Precise Range"](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/preciserange/), which does the right thing.  Looking at [the source](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range/blob/master/readable-range.js), it does something similar to [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064265/634824) - but it properly accounts for the number of days in the month to adjust.

After including both moment.js and this plugin (readable-range.js) in your project, you can simply call it like this:

```
var m1 = moment('2/22/2013','M/D/YYYY');
var m2 = moment('4/5/2014','M/D/YYYY');
var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2);
console.log(diff);
```

The output is "1 year 1 month 14 days"

Comment: How I can add the "Precise Range" to moment.js please?

Comment: It's just another javascript file.  Include it after you include moment.js.

Comment: This is really a great.. Currently it displayed **12 years 10 months 17 days 7 hours 9 minutes 23 seconds** but what if I just want to display the difference in Year and Month? I don't want days!!

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Ask here: https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range/issues.  Or maybe just use `startOf('month')` before you call `preciseDiff`.

Comment: Actually this was silly question, I got this by modifying the `moment-precise-range.js`. The return object was building a string, I just adjusted the string as per my need and it done. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You hardly need moment.

```
d1 = new Date(2014, 3, 5);                // April 5, 2014
d2 = new Date(2013, 1, 22);               // February 22, 2013
diff = new Date(
    d1.getFullYear()-d2.getFullYear(), 
    d1.getMonth()-d2.getMonth(), 
    d1.getDate()-d2.getDate()
);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `Date` constructor is smart about negative values. For instance, if the number of months is negative, it will take that into account and walk back the year.

```
console.log(diff.getYear(), "Year(s),", 
    diff.getMonth(), "Month(s), and", 
    diff.getDate(), "Days.");

>> 1 Year(s), 1 Month(s), and 11 Days.
```

Your calculation is wrong--it's not 14 days, it's six remaining days in February and the first five days of April, so it's 11 days, as the computer correctly computes.

#### Second try

This might work better given @MattJohnson's comment:

```
dy = d1.getYear()  - d2.getYear();
dm = d1.getMonth() - d2.getMonth();
dd = d1.getDate()  - d2.getDate();

if (dd < 0) { dm -= 1; dd += 30; }
if (dm < 0) { dy -= 1; dm += 12; }

console.log(dy, "Year(s),", dm, "Month(s), and", dd, "Days.");
```

Comment: Nice thinking about reusing the `Date` object's ability to walk out of range.  However, there's a few problems with his approach.  1) The `Date` object takes on DST behavior of the local time zone, which can skew certain results, and 2) It doesn't handle whole months well.  Consider Jan 1 - July 1.  Instead of "6 months", it returns "5 months and 30 days".  3) Even then, it doesn't work well with leap years.  Jan 1 - Mar 1 always returns "1 month and 28 days", even if it was in a leap year - where technically it should be "1 month and 29 days".

Comment: Shouldn't Jan. 1 to Mar. 1 always be "two months"?

Comment: Ideally, yes.  I was just pointing out that the value your first pass returned wasn't accurate with regard to leap years.

Comment: The second try code assumes all months are 30 days, which isn't true.  Trust me, this problem is more difficult than it seems. :)  moment has it covered by good understanding of calendar math.  There is indeed a pure JS solution, but it's not simple.

Comment: Actually... As I'm browsing through the moment docs, I am realizing that moment *doesn't* have this operation covered...  I will research more and post an answer later. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Verified with Age calculator.

```
function calculateAge(){
    ageText = jQuery("#dob").closest(".form-group").find(".age-text");
    ageText.text("");
    level2.dob = jQuery("#dob").val();
    if(!level2.dob) return;
    level2.mdob= moment(level2.dob, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    if(!level2.mdob.isValid()){
        alert("Invalid date format");
        return;
    }
    level2.targetDate = moment();//TODO: Fill in the target date
    level2.months = level2.targetDate.diff(level2.mdob, 'months'); // Calculate the months
    let years = parseInt(level2.months/12); // A year has 12 months irrespective or leap year or not
    let balanceMonths = level2.months%12; // The balance gives the number of months 
    let days;
    if(!balanceMonths){ // If no balance months, then the date selected lies in the same month
        months = 0; // so months = 0
        days = level2.targetDate.diff(level2.mdob, 'days'); // only the days difference
    }else{
    months = balanceMonths;
    dob_date = level2.mdob.date();
    target_month = level2.targetDate.month();
    construct_date = moment().month(target_month).date(dob_date);
    days = level2.targetDate.diff(construct_date, 'days')+1; // There might be one day missed out. Not sure on UTC
}

ageText = years +" years " + months+ " months " + days +" days";
}
```