# Jquery get age by input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

How do I calculate the age of a user, depending on the date entered in a textbox?

I want to be able to calculate the exact age of YYYY/MM/DD, so far I've only managed to do it by year.

The code I've tried so far:

```
function OnClick() {
var txtDate = $("#txtDate").val();
var date1 = new Date();
date1.setFullYear(txtDate);
var d1 = date1.getFullYear();
var date2 = new Date();
var d2 = date2.getFullYear();
var age = d2 - d1;
document.getElementById("Diven").innerHTML = age;
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: How old is a person birth in 1st May 2000, and current date is 1st May 2013? How old is a person birth in Feb 29th 2000, while current date is Feb 28th 2010?

Comment: @tsh I don't want to hardcode this, I want to check the current age depending on what the textbox value is

Comment: Yes, I know it is based on current date. I only want to clarify how to consider the age. Will 20101231 ~ 20121231 be considered as 2-year-old, or 3, or 1? And will 20000229 ~ 20020228 be considered as 2-year-old, or 3, or 1? Meaning of age is different from one region to another.

Comment: @tsh From where I see it, on your bithday date, you turn -your new age- so answer to your first question would be '3'. For leaplings, there is indeed regional differences for all legal/administrative purposes (and thus generally important only when you reach majority), but I don't think OP has any interest in this discussions and might just choose whether those people are considered "older" on the 28th of February or the 1st of March...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the date using this: `new Date(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);` you need to subtract `1` from the month. Months are counted from `00`.

For example,

```
var testDate = new Date(1988,10,12) is Sat Nov 12 1988 00:00:00
```

You can try this alternate way:

```
var today = new Date();
var inputBirthDate= new Date(birthYear, birthMonth - 1, birthDay);
var age = today.getFullYear() - inputBirthDate.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth() - inputBirthDate.getMonth();
if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < inputBirthDate.getDate())) {
   age--;
}
console.log(age);
```

This will return you the correct age based on input birth date.

Comment: +1 cause that really looks really like the simplest answer. No complication, straight to the point, exactly how you calculate an age in real life, not with any division, modulo, floor,...

Comment: @pramod-karandikar Thank you sir, as Laurent S said, this works very good and it's how you would do it in real life, sorry for accepting it a bit late, I was very stressed at the time and forgot to check stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

well since i can't make comment, im gonna do it here.

first thing i would do is use momentjs for every date releated thing in js

and if i understand your right, you want something like this?

[How to get difference between 2 Dates in Years, Months and days using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063882/how-to-get-difference-between-2-dates-in-years-months-and-days-using-moment-js)

Comment: beside i would recommend to use something that will force the user to give the right input in the textbox since it wouldn't work if the user input the date like 02-15-1968 since this use '-' instead of '/' And the date format is differencefrom what culture people are from. either something like a date mask, or split it up to 3 input could solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.floor` and the modulo operator `%` for integer division:

```
function CalculateAge() {
    var dob1 = $("#txtBirthday").val();
    var age1 = document.getElementById("#age");

    var dateAry = dob1.value.split("/");
    var birthDay = parseInt(dateAry[0]);
    var birthMonth = parseInt(dateAry[1]);
    var birthYear = parseInt(dateAry[2]);

    var birthDate = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var age = currentDate - birthDate;  // don't forget the var keyword
    var days = Math.floor(age / 86400000); // no need to use a string
    var years = Math.floor(days / 365); // quite inaccurate actually
    var remaning_days = days % 365; // use modulo operator

    age1.value = years;  // no need to type-cast
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function CalculateAge() {
    var dob1 = $("#txtBirthday");
    var age1 = $("#age");
    var dateAry = dob1.val().split("/");
    var birthDay = parseInt(dateAry[0]);
    var birthMonth = parseInt(dateAry[1]);
    var birthYear = parseInt(dateAry[2]);

    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
  var date1 = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2 = new Date();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

  // Convert back to days and return
  var t = difference_ms/one_day;
    age1.val(t/365);
}
```

if you want approx year use Math.random in result