# Can I get the difference between two dates in years and months with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The following will give me years and months:

```
var years = toDate.diff(todaysDate, 'years');
var months = toDate.diff(todaysDate, 'months');
```

so if the difference is 2 years and 2 months, I will get:

```
2
14
```

Can I use moment to get get the differece in this format?

```
2 years, 2 months
```

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate the use of [`from()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get difference between 2 Dates in Years, Months and days using moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063882/how-to-get-difference-between-2-dates-in-years-months-and-days-using-moment-js)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the acepted answer for that question requires an additonal plugin. Which I cannot use.

Comment: The [edit] your question indicating that restriction. I couldn't possibly know that from the existing question.

Comment: You can simply concat the strings right if you want response in a specific format?? Why do you wanna use another helper library when its so simple, why to complicate. :)

Comment: @PrernaJain If I concat the strings, I will get `2 years, 14 months`. Which is no good. I need `2 years, 2 months`.

Comment: okay.. I misunderstood then, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to add additional plug-in you can use modulus operator `%` to convert months to correct value.

Here a working example:

```js
var todaysDate = moment();
var toDate = moment().add(14, 'months');

var years = toDate.diff(todaysDate, 'years');
var months = toDate.diff(todaysDate, 'months');

console.log(years + ' years, ' + months % 12 + ' months');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Another solution using [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) is the following:

```js
var todaysDate = moment();
var toDate = moment().add(14, 'months');

var months = toDate.diff(todaysDate, 'months');

var duration = moment.duration(months, 'months');
console.log(duration.format("y [years] M [months]"));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

In this way you create a duration object from months value and then you format it according your needs using the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Not for the time being. I know that they are working on a plugin for formatting duration, but don't count on that to be released any time soon.

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048