# How to send Timespan to WebAPI from Javascript

Tags: asp.net-web-api, momentjs

I have two moment dates and am calculating the duration by doing the diff between both.

How can I post the duration to the WebAPI controller so that it is automatically deserialize to a C# TimeSpan?
When I post "P2DT00H" it will deserialize properly to a TimeSpan but how can I get that format from a moment duration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculate the duration as described in this answer [Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Define an endpoint like this:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] TimeSpan ts)
    {
        // do stuff
        return Ok(ts);
    }
```

And post the duration like so:

```
POST http://localhost/theendpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

"00:01:10"
```

And web api will deserialize it and bind it to the model correctly.

Comment: This does not seem to work (anymore?)