# Calculate ISO time difference in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

First, I refer :
[Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Then, it doesn't work as I'm using iso time format.

```
var now = '2014-12-12T09:30:00.0000000Z';
var then = '2014-12-12T11:00:00.0000000Z';
var timeDuration = moment.utc(moment(now)).diff(moment(then)).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z";
var now = '2014-12-12T09:30:00.0000000Z';
var then = '2014-12-12T11:00:00.0000000Z';
var timeDuration = moment(moment.utc(moment(then, format)).diff(moment(now, format))).format("HH:mm:ss");
print(timeDuration);
"01:30:00"
```