# calculate time difference in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, time

I want to calculate the difference between the current time and another date which I recuperate from another program. Unfortunalety, this second date is on ISO format ie. in something like that :

```
date2 = "2015-07-16T16:33:39.113Z"
```

I want to calculate the difference between this date2 and the current time and display the difference like that " 0h 53min 10s" for example.
How can I do that in node.js please?

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Did you even try to read any basic tutorial or documentation about JS dates? Or are you simply hoping us SO community will spoon-feed you?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/). You get get the current time via the now() function call and manipulate dates with the framework (use diff()).

```
var moment = require('moment');

date2 = "2015-07-16T16:33:39.113Z"

var then = moment(date2, "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ");
var now = moment();

var diff = moment.duration(then.diff(now));
if (diff < 0) {
    diff = Math.abs(diff);
}
var d = moment.utc(diff).format("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
console.log("Difference: " + d);
```

For reference, see [Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Understood, added a sample solution. Tested and working.