# How can I get time betweend a moment and now as a duration?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to know how long ago a moment(date) is.

```
moment.duration(moment() - date)
```

Works, but I think it's a bit clunky. Is there a cleaner way of doing it? Can I otherwise extend duration with a method like this and should I?

Comment: I think this one is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: That looks even more complicated than my solution :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would rely only on `moment` methods is this: `moment.duration( moment().subtract(date) )`  but I am not sure it really improves on your code.  Durations are context-less so you can't compare a date directly with it, I think.