# How to update date diff automatically

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework, momentjs

i'm trying to show the difference between now and a date using moment into my ionic app.

This is what i'm trying:

**controller**

```
this.getElapsedTime = function(){
    return moment(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(this.user.date))).format("HH:mm:ss");
};
```

**view**

```
<span class="footer-title">Tempo trascorso: {{myCtrl.getElapsedTime()}}</span>
```

My problem is that date will automatically update view just for a second and then it doesn't change.

How can i tell to angular to update always the view?

Comment: Aside: Your moment code can be simplified to `moment.utc(moment().diff(this.user.date)).format("HH:mm:ss")`.  Also, you should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18624295/634824) about how to correctly format durations if they might go over 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend relying on Angular bindings to change something so frequently, because the only way for them to update is to do a full digest, which can kill performance if you do it too often.

Instead, create a directive that takes in a date value and then directly manipulates the element's `innerHTML` to update the time remaining in a `setInterval()` function.

*Don't forget to cancel the interval in the `$destroy` scope event to prevent memory leaks.*