# Wrong time difference with momentjs diff function

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

i'm trying to calculate the difference between two UTC Datetime Strings with angular-momentjs like shown below:

```
var start = "1970-01-01T11:03:00.000Z";
var end = "1970-01-01T11:15:00.000Z";

var duration = $moment.utc($moment(end).diff($moment(start))).format("hh:mm");
```

when i execute the code above, the duration should be 00:12 but actually it is 12:12. I don't understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the time difference between two datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually creating a *moment.js* object for 1970-01-01T00:12:00.000Z, then getting the time as hour and minutes. The token "hh" is for 12 hour time, so you're seeing "12" for 12am. If you want to see 00:12, use the token "HH" which gives 24 hour time: 00:12.