# MomentJS date conversion

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm working with jQuery time entry plugin
http://keith-wood.name/timeentry.html

This plugin is returning data in "12:23PM" javascript typeof "string", and now using momentjs I want to convert it into time and get difference between current time & user selected time.

```
var a = new Date($("#totime").val())
```

I'm getting error `Invalid Date`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [string-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) moment constructor to pass string and format in which input string is. To calculate the [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method can be used.

*Use*

```js
var t = "12:23PM";
var cdt = moment(t, 'HH:mmA');
console.log(cdt.toDate());
console.log('difference in milliseconds: ', cdt.diff(moment()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: The difference is in milliseconds.But I need in hrs:min format

Comment: @Varanasi, Yes, I have clearly mentioned __difference in milliseconds:__ You can pass `a.diff(b, 'days')`

Comment: var _a = $scope.Booking.FromTime;
            var _b = $scope.Booking.ToTime;
            var _a2 = moment(_a, "HH:mmA")
            var _b2 = moment(_b, "HH:mmA");
            var c = _a2.diff(_b2, 'days');
            $log.warn(c);

Comment: I'm working with angularjs, in above code what I have given, is giving me NaN. _a carries current time, _b carries user given time. Im trying to calculate difference.