# Is there any way to get the difference between two datetime in moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Let's Say, I've a two datetime moment date time object.

```
momentdatefirst = '2017-03-21T05:00:00+05:45'

momentdatesecond = '1990-03-21T07:12:45+05:45'
```

How do calculate the difference between these two time stamps in moment.js?

I tried this:

```
var diff_hour = momentdatefirst.diff(momentdatesecond);
```

And this doesn't retrieve the actual difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the time difference between two datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: Sorry, My bug was not because of the diff method but due to the two different date format between first and second date. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this:

```
let date = moment('2017-03-21T05:00:00+05:45');
let dateTwo = moment('1990-03-21T07:12:45+05:45');
let diff = dateTwo.diff(date); // in milliseconds
let diffInHours = date.diff(dateTwo, 'hour'); // in hours
// and so on
console.log('diff in milliseconds', diff);
```

It will output `852068835000` milliseconds which ~ 27 years.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = moment('2016-06-06T21:03:55');//now
var b = moment('2016-05-06T20:03:55');

console.log(a.diff(b, 'minutes')) // 44700
console.log(a.diff(b, 'hours')) // 745
console.log(a.diff(b, 'days')) // 31
console.log(a.diff(b, 'weeks')) // 4
```

You can go through moment docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)