# How to subtract and plus date in react native

Tags: react-native

Actually, i am stuck in one problem that is about Date.

I want to subtract and plus the date in react native.

is there any solution about it.

I have used Moment.js but the error occurs in it so please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check below working example of add and subtract day, month and date using moment:

**For Day**

```
let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow = moment(tomorrow).add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // for specific format

let today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

let tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow = moment(tomorrow).add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**For Month**

```
moment(currentMonth).add(1, 'month');
moment(currentMonth).subtract(1, 'month');
```

**For Date**

```
let now  = "14/11/2016";
let then = "03/12/2017";

let diff = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY"));
let duration = moment.duration(diff);
let result = duration.format("hh:mm:ss");
```

Please refer detailed date difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624295/6592263

**EDIT** (Not tested)

**To get Month**

```
let d = moment(new Date());
d.month(); // month number
d.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY');
```

**TO get Year**

```
let d = moment(new Date());
d.year() // year
```

Comment: and one more thing is. If i want to subtract and add a year so that is same as above month.?

Comment: and can you please tell me how to subtract month..actually i got an error.

Comment: so please give full code of month and year please like a You gave the demo of day..

Comment: how do i get currentMonth

Comment: That is bit complicated to share, as I have many files to handle that

Comment: okay but just tell me about the month and year please..just simple demonstration like you gave a day demo above

Comment: Updated answer, but note that not tested

Answer (score 7):

If you want to take today date and add a year, month or a day, you can first create a date object, access the relevant properties, and then use them to create a new date object:

```
    const date = new Date();

    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const day = date.getDate();

    const c = new Date(year + 1, month, day) // PLUS 1 YEAR
    const d = new Date(year, month + 1, day) // PLUS 1 MONTH
    const f = new Date(year, month, day  + 1) // PLUS 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case was to get end date after adding some months. This works without using moment.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
   var monthNames = [
     "January", "February", "March",
     "April", "May", "June", "July",
     "August", "September", "October",
     "November", "December"
   ];

   var day = date.getDate();
   var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
   var year = date.getFullYear();

   return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
 }
     

function add_months_todate(dt, no_of_month) 
     {
       return new Date(dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + no_of_month));      
     }
    
    start_date = new Date();
    end_date = add_months_todate(new Date(), 10); 

console.log("START DATE",formatDate(start_date));
console.log("END DATE",formatDate(end_date));
```

Reference :https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-43.php