# cant get the datetime difference in javascript(nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date-fns

I am trying to get the day/hr/min difference from two JavaScript datetime stamps, the current time subtract a future event time which will then be displayed on the application front end.

two dates:
Future event date - 2017-10-01 18:00:00
Current date - now()

Current code:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var eventStarts = results[0][i].eventstarts;
var difference = differenceInMilliseconds(eventStarts, currentTime);
var date = new Date(difference);
var days = date.getDay();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var formattedTime = days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
```

This isn't correctly working and i cant figure out why, its returning a 2 day difference which obviously isn't correct, it should be returning upwards of 29 days.

I'm currently using the npm package date-fns and i don't mind trying out another package if that will help out

Comment: have you tried moment http://momentjs.com/?

Comment: Take care when spelling JavaScript to avoid search conflict with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a `Date`, it's based on the 1st january 1970. So when you are setting up `new Date(difference)`. You are setting a date related to 1st january 1970 - so not what you are looking for.

I would recommand you to use the library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), that allow easy date manipulation.

---

@manzurul example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);

console.log(d.days(), d.hours(), d.minutes(), d.seconds());
```

Comment: ah okay, that makes sense, ive never used moment.js before how would my code work with moment.js?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes) is a stackoverflow post about getting the difference between two dates