# i have a date and time, i want to conver into a relativeTime like twitter. i tried moment.js but it dost not work

Tags: javascript, time, relative-time-span

I am looking for to convert this date and time to **relative time** like twitter have **ex. 5 sec ago or 1 month ago**.
I have stored date and time in different column of database.
i am executing this in **JavaScript**, i tried **Momentjs** but it does not work well or i may not understand its format or flow of work.
i am little new to javascript, i started learning react a week ago
from database:

date =>31.03.2019 time=>16:06:05

**Thank You For Help.**

Success Update :
Mission was to convert "31.3.2019 19:45:55" this date into a time like twitter or facebook have.

```
let date = new Date()

   var then = request.date +' '+ request.time;

 var ms = moment(date,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
  var d = moment.duration(ms);
  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
  var timeAgo = d.humanize();;
```

In moment we can define the format of date we are passing and with humanize function its easy to get the desire output.
What i didnt know was the definition of format of date we pass. #NOW I AM CLEAR SIR. 
Thank You For Helping Everybody. Thank You For Sharing .

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Please show your work.

Comment: var rightNow = (day +'/'+ month +'/'+ year+ ' '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds);
                console.log(rightNow);  // 31/2/2019 19:52:44
                var then = "31/03/2019 18:51:44";
                console.log(then);  //31/03/2019 18:51:44
                var ms = moment(rightNow,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
                var d = moment.duration(ms);
                var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
                console.log(s); //NaNInvalidDate

Comment: var rightNow = (day +'/'+ month +'/'+ year+ ' '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds);
                console.log(rightNow);  // 31/2/2019 19:52:44
                var then = "31/03/2019 18:51:44";
                console.log(then);  //31/03/2019 18:51:44
                var ms = moment(rightNow,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
                var d = moment.duration(ms);
                var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
                console.log(s); //NaNInvalidDate

Comment: @OnurArı so far so now i have did this

Comment: let date = new Date()
                var then = "27.03.2019 18:51:44";
  var ms = moment(date,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
                var d = moment.duration(ms);
                var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
                console.log(d); //Successfully get the object with value. trying to access the value now. Thank you all. help me to aceess object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**moment js**](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
let date = new Date()

console.log(moment(date).fromNow())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do i access the object return by moment

Comment: @RahulShahare what do you mean by this  `how do i access the object return by moment` ? you can access as you access any other function in JS and assign return value to any variable you want