# How to do when 'countdown timer' has run out and then run the function 'alert()' in 'Momentjs'

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, momentjs

Here I use Codeigniter and MomentJS, How to run the 'alert()' function when 'contdown timer' has run out

in Main.JS

```
var timeEvent = <?=$timeEvent?>;
var timeNow = <?=now('America/Santiago')?>;
var diff = timeEvent - timeNow;
var duration = moment.duration(diff*1000, 'milliseconds');
var interval = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
  duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
  $('#result').text(duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds());
}, interval);
```

Comment: Look at this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129157/countdown-timer-using-moment-js#answer-38022466

Comment: put an if statement after the duration is set and check the value of duration, if it's <= 0 fire your alert.

Comment: As an aside, note that `setInterval()` isn't guaranteed to run at exactly the specified interval, so if you're displaying a countdown it is normal practice to factor the current time into your calculation rather than just subtracting the same value every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely it's this simple no?

```
setInterval(function(){
  duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
  if( duration <= 0 ) {
    alert("Done");
  }
  $('#result').text(duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds());
}, interval);
```

Comment: Thx, It's Work :)

Comment: By the way, how to add 'clearInterval' ? Is it just like this                            
  if( duration <= 0 ) {
    alert("Done"); clearInterval();
  }